# Check if registry key exists always fails

Tags: installation, nsis

I am trying to determine if a Registry key exists or not. I am using a macro someone has made but its not correctly identifying that a registry key exists

It says that a certain key doesn't exist when it actually does. Am I using this [macro](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Check_for_a_Registry_Key) incorrectly?

My code, the path to the registry key is correct:

```
!insertmacro IfKeyExists "HKLM" "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${COMPANYNAME}\${APPNAME}" "Version"
Pop $R0
MessageBox MB_OK "Exists: $R0" # always is zero when shd be 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this a lot simpler by issuing a read operation on the key (`ReadRegStr` for example) and then check if any error occurs using Logiclib. Functionally, a key that does not exist is equivalent to a key you cannot read...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are talking about the correct key (Meaning you need to watch out for WOW64 separation and registry virtualization) Monitor the installer with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)...